# Set of pairs, compilation error

Tags: java

I want to know why this piece of code gets a compilation error. I'm new to JAVA. I wanted to make a Set of pairs as in C++
What is the meaning of **pair** in inner class code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Set;

public class UVa {
    public static boolean flag = false;
    public static Integer p0, p1;
    public static Set<pair<Integer,Integer> > sorter;

    public static class pair<first,second>{
        public first First;
        public second Second;
        private pair(first First,second Second){
            this.First = First;
            this.Second = Second;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                p0 = System.in.read();
                p1 = System.in.read();
                sorter.add(pair<p0, p1>); //<<Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message?

Comment: As an aside, Java convention is for types to begin with capitals, and variables with lowercase letters (e.g. public First first, <First, Second> etc.).

Comment: You can read all about the Java naming conventions (and other recommended Java coding conventions) [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At line no 8:**

```
public static Set<pair<Integer,Integer> > sorter;
```

Set is not initialize yet that's why is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`  , So for that you have ho initialize it first like following.

```
public static Set<pair<Integer,Integer> > sorter = new HashSet<UVa.pair<Integer,Integer>>();
```

**And at line no 25**
You are try to add `pair<p0, p1>` in to set like you are doing

```
 sorter.add(pair<p0, p1>);
```

But its not a correct syntax . The correct syntax  is .

```
sorter.add(new pair<Integer, Integer>(p0, p1));
```

or

```
sorter.add(new pair(p0, p1))
```

Comment: gives runtime error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 5):

It appears you're trying to construct a new `pair` using

```
pair<p0, p1>
```

However, the correct syntax is

```
new pair<Integer, Integer>(p0, p1)
```

Comment: Note: Perhaps it would be a better idea to learn that kind of basic Java stuff, before dabbling into generics? :)

Comment: Since the `pair` class uses generics, shouldn't it really be `new pair<Integer, Integer>(p0, p1)`?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to add to your Set is an object of type `pair<Integer, Integer>`. To create one of these you need to use the `new` keyword, and call the constructor with the two Integer variables `p0` and `p1`.

```
sorter.add(new pair<Integer, Integer>(p0,p1));
```

It's [conventional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) to name classes with a leading capital. I've rewritten your `pair` class below with these conventions, to try and show how it uses [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) more clearly:

```
public static class Pair<T1,T2>{
    public T1 first;
    public T2 second;
    private pair(T1 first, T2 second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RofaelEmil That's a runtime error; What line is causing it? The above should compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

Changed your code :

```
 pair p= new pair<Integer, Integer>(p0, p1);
            sorter.add(p); //<<Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token
```

Comment: gives runtime error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
sorter.add(pair<p0, p1>);
```

Read

```
sorter.add(new pair(p0, p1));
```

Comment: gives runtime error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

In your source, `pair<p0, p1>` in the statement `sorter.add(pair<p0, p1>);` refers to the type `pair`. You are not actually creating an object to be added to the set. You might as well have written `sorter.add(int);`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Java.  While Java is C++, the programming style is a little different.  Try the following. Getting `pair` to compile is just the first of your problems. ;)

```
public class UVa {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sorter = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            int p0 = scanner.nextInt();
            int p1 = scanner.nextInt();
            sorter.add(Pair.of(p0, p1));
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

        Collections.sort(sorter, new Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) {
                int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.first, o2.first);
                if (cmp == 0)
                    cmp = Integer.compare(o1.second, o2.second);
                return cmp;
            }
        });
        for (Pair<Integer, Integer> pair : sorter) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
    }
}

class Pair<First, Second> {
    public final First first;
    public final Second second;

    public Pair(First first, Second second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static Pair<Integer, Integer> of(int i, int j) {
        return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(i, j);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair{" +
                "first=" + first +
                ", second=" + second +
                '}';
    }
}
```